# OAS log files filling up hard drive

Tags: oracle, log-files

We've had issues with log files for Oracle Application Server filling up the hard drive on our server.  The files are in the /network/admin folder and are named server.log_XXXXX.trc and client.log_XXXXX.trc where XXXXX are 5 digits. The files are typically anywhere from 1-2MB in size but can be up to 100MB and thousands of them are created at a rate of about 5-10 per minute.

Does anyone know how to disable these logs?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the exact path to the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your sqlnet.ora file which is also under network/admin.  It probably has some tracing options turned on.